# Python: Searching values inside deeply nested lists

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a really long nested list, that looks something like this

```
['a','b',['c','d',['e',['a','b',['c','d',['e',['a','b',['c','d',['e4',['a','b',['c','d',['e',['a','b',['c','d',['e',['a','b',['c','d',['e14']]]]]],]]]]]]]]],]]]
```

I'm trying to find `value` inside that list, however in my case a normal for loops doesn't works because i need to loop through each one and that would take so long.

I came up with this recursive function:

```
def locate(seq :list, value:int):
    for item in seq:
        if item.__class__ is list:
            locate(item, value)
        else:
            if(item == value):
                return True
    return False
```

So here is the unit test that i created for my algorithm:

```
import unittest

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_locate(self):
        self.assertEqual(locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'e'), True)

    def test_locate_two(self):
        self.assertEqual(locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e',['a','b',['c','d',['e',['a','b',['c','d',['e4',['a','b',['c','d',['e',['a','b',['c','d',['e',['a','b',['c','d',['e14']]]]]],]]]]]]]]],]]],'e'), True)

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Test result:

```
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Comment: does your requirements met now with recusive usage?

Comment: @DARK_C0D3R yup, it's not raising MemoryError

Comment: You should modify `locate(item,value)` to `return locate(item, value)`

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal why? then it would be returning `False` in first iteration when it founds a list

Comment: Also tried with `return locate(item, value)` this algorithm still fails some cases

Comment: @yagizcandegirmenci Yeah, indeed it will return false in the case if there is a list without `e` character in it, before the actual character occurs. My comment was for the test cases you provided. I will try to think of the overall recursion logic for a case which works for more cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I tried this modification:

```
def locate(seq :list, value:int):
el_check = False
for item in seq:
    if item.__class__ is list:
        el_check = el_check or locate(item, value)
    else:
        if(item == value):
            return True
return el_check
```

Seems to work in couple tests, if you find a case it does not work at, please post so I can try to have a look at it.